# Creation of SparkContext in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jvm

I am wondering which process creates SparkContext in PySpark applications. I understood that there will be a Python main process and a JVM one and it sounded like the python main script will spawn the JVM one but not so sure that's accurate. I have two questions:

1. Which one actually creates SparkContext? I am guessing it is the JVM one and it will be passed to the Python main process?
2. If I run my PySpark via spark-submit, it looks like it is the JVM process? Would this be the one creating SparkContext?

Overall it is not clear to me whether there are any differences in running Pyspark codes with spark-submit vs. with python interpreter (python3 my_pyspark.py for example) in terms of which one creates the SparkContext.